# Building web,mobile architecture with firebase, angular4

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase

We were doing **survey like web** app in rails framework adding API functionality to support iOS and Android in future.

Recently I learned about firebase and I really liked it. It fits for iOS and Android very well. I am not sure does it fit for web.

My plan is to use `Angular4+Ionic+Firebase` frameworks to build hybrid app.
Then to build web app using `Angular4+Firebase`. As far as i know implementing whole business logic in frontend is not secure in N-tier architecture. Because survey results will be calculated in front end.

Simply I want to use firebase for web app:
There are two options for me. Not sure which one is more preferred.

```
 1. Angular4+Firebase
 2. Angular4 + Nodejs + Firebase
```

Can you suggest preferred way to build web app using firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is a serveless technology, however you can use Firebase Cloud Functions to keep your business rule.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Angular 4 as your Frontend, Node as your backend to create WebApis, and FireBase to store your data as it can work as Realtime Database